# How do I configure helm-git-grep candidates limit?

Tags: helm, helm-grep

I have this in my `.emacs` file but it still shows that the limit is 300 Candidates.

```
(require 'helm-git-grep) ;; Not necessary if installed by package.el

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c g") 'helm-git-grep)

(setq helm-candidate-number-limit 200)
```

Comment: What is "it" in "it still shows ..."?

Answer (score 0):

try customizing the variable `helm-git-grep-candidate-number-limit`. I used `M-x customize-variable` to do it interactively.